# how to split string array values in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

how to split string array value and then store representive string variable? like this name=name

```
class Test{
   public static void main(String[] args){

   String myarray[] ={"name","age","qualification","gender"};
   String name;
   String gender;
   String qualification,
   String age;

     for(int i =0;i<myarray.length;i++){
         name=myarray[i];
    }
```

}

Comment: this question doesn't seem clear to me. Try a better question it you need a better answer.

Comment: @user1356713 i need to split myarray[] values and then splitted values store into representive string variable
for example
name=name
age=age
qualification=qualification
gender=gender

Comment: It seems you've already answered your question.  Your code above stores the splitted array into representative variables.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:  Not *really*; all that code does is keep it in an array location, in which one has to remember which location holds what information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do it unless you deploy some super-sophisticated reflection tactics, which would be far from helpful at your perceived level.

Instead, you can actually do something a bit simpler.  If you know you're always going to get an array of size 4 and those positions will always contain that data, you can refer to them by their index position.  You would also benefit from giving that index position a meaningful name so that you don't forget what you're getting from it.

```
final int NAME = 0;
final int AGE = 1;
final int QUALIFICATION = 2;
final int GENDER = 3;

// refer to them by the constants above
name = myarray[NAME];
// repeat for the others
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't do something like following?

```
    String myarray[] = {"name", "age", "qualification", "gender"};
    String name;
    String gender;
    String qualification;
    String age;
    for (String i : myarray) {
        switch (i) {
            case "name":
                name = i;
                break;
            case "age":
                age = i;
                break;
            case "qualification":
                qualification = i;
                break;
            case "gender":
                gender = i;
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't use a for loop here.
Just use 
`name=myarray[0];
age=myarray[1];
qualification=myarray[2];
gender=myarray[3];`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a HashMap instead of String you could do something like this :

> ```
>   String myarray[] = {"name", "age", "qualification", "gender"};
>
>   HashMap<String, String> foo = new HashMap<String, String>();
>
>   for(String i : myarray) {
>       foo.put(i, i);
>   }
>
>   System.out.println(foo.get("name"));
>   System.out.println(foo.get("age"));
>   System.out.println(foo.get("qualification"));
>   System.out.println(foo.get("gender"));
> ```

This way you don't have to remember which index of an array holds which information but just the name of the key, as you would have to remember the name of the variable.